# PHP Form returning weird results in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to make a drop down that links to the option once the user presses the submit button, but I'm getting weird results. It's worth mentioning that this is in Wordpress so I'm not sure if its affecting the results at all.

```
<form id="select-id">
<select name="page">
 <option >Select Area</option>
 <option value="/condo/etobicoke/">Etobicoke</option>
 <option value="/condo/toronto/">Toronto</option>
 <option value="/condo/north-york/">North York</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"">
</form>

<script> 
$('#select-id').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   url = $('#select-id').val();
   window.open(url);
});
</script>
```

The result for the first option is `domainname.com?page=%2Fcondo%2Fetobicoke%2F`
but I want `domainname.com/condo/etobicoke/`

Answer (score 0):

You're grabbing the wrong value in your JavaScript. You need the `field` value, not the `form` value

```
$('#select-id').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $('[name="page"]').val();
    window.open(url);
});
```

Check out this pen: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/VXePqM?editors=1111

I've changed it to `console.log` instead of window opening for demonstration purposes

Answer (score -1):

The %2F is the same as a / character it's just been converted. Also if your domain is as domainname.com?page=%2Fcondo%2Fetobicoke%2F then you need to change your permalink structure in wordpress and maybe add rewrite functions if the link contains custom parameters.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule